# I m trying to initialize docker container using variable value in terraform but facing this error

Tags: docker, terraform

```
PS C:\Users\PAHARNE\Terraform\Q2> terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/random...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/docker-image...
- Finding kreuzwerker/docker versions matching "2.11.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/google...
- Installing hashicorp/random v3.1.0...
- Installed hashicorp/random v3.1.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing kreuzwerker/docker v2.11.0...
- Installed kreuzwerker/docker v2.11.0 (self-signed, key ID 24E54F214569A8A5)
- Installing hashicorp/google v3.69.0...
- Installed hashicorp/google v3.69.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/plugins/signing.html
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/docker-image: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a
│ provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/docker-image
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will
│ get the correct providers when using a module. To see which modules are currently
│ depending on hashicorp/docker-image, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
╵
```

Comment: It says you have specified a Terraform provider named `hashicorp/docker-image` which does not exist. You need to edit your question to show your Terraform template.

Comment: which version of terraform you are using. If possible check with a more recent version, or try version = ">= 2.11.0" instead of version = " 2.11.0"

Answer (score 1):

`hashicorp/docker-image` is not a provider that exists. You can search for available providers in the [Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/).

See if you have a terraform file containing something along the lines of:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "hashicorp/docker-image"
    }
  }
}
```

The above would be invalid since that provider does not exist. You can change that source to something from the registry for a valid provider.

It's also possible your state file may still contain an incorrect source, running `terraform providers` will show you if this is the case. Then you can run a `terraform state replace-provider` command and fix the incorrect source with the correct source. –

Comment: terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "2.11.0"
    }
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
    }
    random = {
      source = "hashicorp/random"
    }
  
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}

provider "docker" {
}                  I already added this still same error

Comment: In this case, your state file may still contain an incorrect source, running `terraform providers` will show you if this is the case. Then you can run a `terraform state replace-provider` command and fix the incorrect source with the correct source.

Comment: Great! If this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted.